# Using global variables to push tags to Git in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I cannot wrap my head around using global variables in Git commands.
I have the following code:

```
stage('Publish to GIT') {
    steps {
        bat 'git push -v origin website-0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}'
    }
}
```

BUILD_NUMBER is a global variable used in Jenkins but I cannot get it to resolve. I also tried using Powershell but to no avail.
I also tried `${BUILD_NUMBER}` `$BUILD_NUMBER` but without success.

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

when you are using pipelines be notted that it is groovy , which means you have to follow code/syntax rulles. in your snippet the only mistake is that you are using ' in stead of " which means follwing:
usage of ' - whatever is inside is treated as String, so ${env.BUILD_NUMBER} wont be executed 
usage of " - whatever is inside is teated as String, apart from ${SOMETHING} which will be executed and changed with the value of the var

having that in mind you have to have following instead what you have now:

```
stage('Publish to GIT') {
    steps {
        sh|bat "git push -v origin website-0.${env.BUILD_NUMBER}"
    }
}
```

Comment: My pleasure , ping if you face more troubles with piprlines